# How to scroll QListWidget to selected item

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlistwidget

The code below creates a single dialog window with `QListWidget` and `QPushButton`.
Clicking the button fires up a `scroll()` function which finds and selects an "ITEM-0011".

I wonder if there is a way to scroll the list widget so the selected `ITEM-0011` is at the top edge of `QListWidget`? Here is how the end result should look like:

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication([])

def scroll():
    item = listWidget.findItems('ITEM-0011', QtCore.Qt.MatchRegExp)[0]
    item.setSelected(True)

window = QtGui.QDialog()
window.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget()
window.layout().addWidget(listWidget)

for i in range(100):
    QtGui.QListWidgetItem('ITEM-%04d'%i, listWidget)

btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Scroll')
btn.clicked.connect(scroll)
window.layout().addWidget(btn)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Did you look at the docs for qlistwidget before asking this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The list-widget has a [scrollToItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#scrollToItem) method that will scroll an item to a [specific position](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#ScrollHint-enum):

```
def scroll():
    item = listWidget.findItems('ITEM-0011', QtCore.Qt.MatchRegExp)[0]
    item.setSelected(True)
    listWidget.scrollToItem(item, QtGui.QAbstractItemView.PositionAtTop)
```