# Python regular expressions with Foreign characters in python PyQT5

Tags: python-3.x, regex, qt, pyqt5, python-re

This problem might be very simple but I find it a bit confusing & that is why I need help.

With relevance to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65557173/how-qregularexpression-can-be-passed-to-qtmatchregularexpression) I posted that got solved, I got a new issue that I just noticed.

---

**Source code:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtWidgets

app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])

def scroll():
    #QtCore.QRegularExpression(r'\b'+'cat'+'\b')
    item = listWidget.findItems(r'\bcat\b', QtCore.Qt.MatchRegularExpression)
    for d in item:
        print(d.text())

window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
window.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
window.layout().addWidget(listWidget)


cats = ["love my cat","catirization","cat in the clouds","catść"]

for i,cat in enumerate(cats):
    QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(f"{i}  {cat}", listWidget)

btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Scroll')
btn.clicked.connect(scroll)
window.layout().addWidget(btn)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

**Output GUI:**

[image: PYQT5 OUTPUT GUI]

---

Now as you can see I am just trying to print out the text data based on the regex `r"\bcat\b"` when I press the **"Scroll"** button and it works fine!

**Output:**

```
0  love my cat
2  cat in the clouds
3  catść
```

However... as you can see on the **#3**, it should not be printed out cause it obviously does not match with the mentioned regular expression which is `r"\bcat\b"`. However it does & I am thinking it has something to do with that special foreign character **ść** that makes it a match & prints it out (which it shouldn't right?).

**I'm expecting an output like:**

```
0  love my cat
2  cat in the clouds
```

### Researches I have tried

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009993/what-would-be-regex-for-matching-foreign-characters) and it says something about this `\p{L}` & based on the answer it means:

> If all you want to match is letters (including "international"
> letters) you can use \p{L}.

To be honest I'm not so sure how to apply that with PyQT5 also still I've made some tries & and I tried changing the regex to like this `r'\b'+r'\p{cat}'+r'\b'`. However I got this error.

```
QString::contains: invalid QRegularExpression object
QString::contains: invalid QRegularExpression object
QString::contains: invalid QRegularExpression object
QString::contains: invalid QRegularExpression object
```

Obviously the error says it's not a valid regex. Can someone educate me on how to solve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: You should pass the `QRegularExpression::UseUnicodePropertiesOption` option. Or, use `r'(*UCP)\bcat\b'`

Comment: oh my! Amazing! @WiktorStribiżew it's so unbelievable how people here can solve an issue in just seconds while I'm here figuring it out for hours... this regex you provided worked! but may I ask what does `UCP` stand for? Also I'd love to learn how to do this that you mentioned **pass the QRegularExpression::UseUnicodePropertiesOption option**. Do you happen to know how to do it with `PYQT5?` Thank you

Comment: I'd really love to learn how to do it since it's also a good option to do as a solution to this issue. If yes you can kindly post it as an answer along with the regex you provided.

Comment: 1) `r'\b'+r'\p{cat}'+r'\b'` is **exactly** the same as `r'\b\p{cat}\b'`; do some research on string concatenation, as it's directly related to the previous problem you had (for which you did *not* add the prefix instead). 2) Don't ask "what does UCP" stand for, look up for it (it's pretty clear that it stands for the same thing as the `UseUnicodePropertiesOption`, as UCP is its acronym).

Comment: 1) I know that, I just wanted the first one cause I'm using my text editor and the color differs from the other one, I just like it, **my eyes likes it**. 2.) I got hyped by @Wiktor and googled UCP but found a different results, now I got it.

Comment: What if you specify a QRegularExpression and pass it to the findItems method? `rx = Qt.QRegularExpression(r'\bcat\b', Qt.UseUnicodePropertiesOption)` and then use `item = listWidget.findItems(rx, Qt.MatchRegularExpression)`

Comment: Ah, I see, that probably should be `rx = QtCore.QRegularExpression(r'\bcat\b', QtCore.QRegularExpression.UseUnicodePropertiesOption)`

Comment: I tried this one `rx = QtCore.Qt.QRegularExpression(r'\bcat\b', QtCore.Qt.UseUnicodePropertiesOption)` I just based it on my imports. `item = listWidget.findItems(rx, QtCore.Qt.MatchRegularExpression)` but I got this error: `AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'QRegularExpression'`

Comment: I think it's `from PyQt5.QtCore import QRegularExpression` so it would be `QtCore.QRegularExpression`. I'll try

Comment: I got this error tho :/ `TypeError: findItems(self, str, Union[Qt.MatchFlags, Qt.MatchFlag]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QRegularExpression'` but I can see where this is going and the implementation of this `rx = QtCore.QRegularExpression(r'\bcat\b', QtCore.QRegularExpression.UseUnicodePropertiesOption)` is **CORRECT**. It's just the `findItems` function first param expecting a string `str`.

Comment: This means, you might have to only rely on the `(*UCP)` PCRE verb if all you can do is use a *string* regex pattern (and not a regex object).

Comment: hmmm... I see I guess that's fine! Thanks a lot! I think you can post the answer please cause I do sometimes make this (my questions) as notes. Also other people might find it useful! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when you need to make your shorthand character classes and word boundaries Unicode-aware, you need to pass the `QRegularExpression.UseUnicodePropertiesOption` option to the regex compiler. See the [`QRegularExpression.UseUnicodePropertiesOption` reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#PatternOption-enum):

> The meaning of the `\w`, `\d`, etc., character classes, as well as the meaning of their counterparts (`\W`, `\D`, etc.), is changed from matching ASCII characters only to matching any character with the corresponding Unicode property. For instance, `\d` is changed to match any character with the Unicode `Nd` (decimal digit) property; `\w` to match any character with either the Unicode `L` (letter) or `N` (digit) property, plus underscore, and so on. This option corresponds to the `/u` modifier in Perl regular expressions.

In Python, you could declare it as

```py
rx = QtCore.QRegularExpression(r'\bcat\b', QtCore.QRegularExpression.UseUnicodePropertiesOption)
```

However, since the [`QListWidget.findItems`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#findItems) does not support a QRegularExpression as argument and only allows the regex as a string object, you can only use the `(*UCP)` PCRE
verb as an alternative:

```
r'(*UCP)\bcat\b'
```

Make sure you define it at the regex beginning.